# PHP str_replace is not working as expected

Tags: php, str-replace

```
$replace = 'replace';
$my_string = ' abC.com, Abc.net, aBc.org, ABC.info, aBC.biz '; 
$lowerCase = 'abc';
$str_replace = str_replace($lowerCase, $replace, $my_string);
echo $str_replace;
```

**I need result as follows**: replace.com, replace.net, replace.org, replace.info, replace.biz

Comment: use `str_ireplace`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Answer (score 0):

As the [PHP manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php):

> str_ireplace — Case-insensitive version of str_replace().

So you should use `str_ireplace`

```
$str_replace = str_ireplace($lowerCase, $replace, $my_string);
```

But note, that character case is being defined by your server's locale setting, which affects strings containing non-ASCII characters.

You could also use `strtolower`:

```
$str_replace = str_replace($lowerCase, $replace, strtolower($my_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

[strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) $my_string and write your code for your results. [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

```
$replace = 'replace';
$my_string = ' abC.com, Abc.net, aBc.org, ABC.info, aBC.biz '; 
$lowerCase = 'abc';
$str_replace = str_replace($lowerCase, $replace, strtolower($my_string));
echo $str_replace;
```